How to setup local dev environment with docker compose and few web services that share common domain
I need to have locally setup docker compose with 3 services that are map to subdomains, f.e.:

nginx.app.com
service1.app.com
service2.app.com
service3.app.com

It is important to share common domain like *app.com, cause I need this setup for JSESSION cookie testing.
Is such configuration feasible to achieve with docker compose and nginx docker service.
I have already docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./nginx/generate-certs.sh:/usr/local/bin/generate-certs.sh
    entrypoint: /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/generate-certs.sh && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    depends_on:
      - service1
      - service2
      - service3

  service1:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html

  service2:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    volumes:
      - ./html2:/usr/share/nginx/html

  service3:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8083:80"
    volumes:
      - ./html3:/usr/share/nginx/html


and nginx.conf:
events {
}
http {
    upstream service1 {
        server service1:80;
    }
    upstream service2 {
        server service2:80;
    }
    upstream service3 {
        server service3:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.app.com;
        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name service3.app.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://service3;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name service1.app.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        location /1 {
            proxy_pass http://service1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name service2.app.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        location /2 {
            proxy_pass http://service2;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name service3.app.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        location /3 {
            proxy_pass http://service3;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}


whenever I access https://app.com it serves me well (I've added this host to /etc/hosts)
but I can not reach https://service3.app.com from host - my pc browser
To sum up, I need this kind of architecture:

https://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker/
please point me what I am doing wrong.

Docker can't configure external DNS and doesn't try to change system configuration files like /etc/hosts.  This sort of hostname-based routing can't be set up with Docker alone; you need something outside of Docker to configure those host names.
Since you already have a reverse proxy, a good first thing to try is just to combine all of its blocks into a single HTTP service, like
server {
  listen 80;
  location /1/ {
    proxy_pass http://service1;
  }
  location /2/ {
    proxy_pass http://service2;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://service3;
  }
}

Then you'd be able to call e.g. http://localhost/1/ and get routed to service1.  (If that service constructs absolute URLs in some way, it may need to know it's behind a proxy that inserts this path prefix.)  This doesn't depend on host names at all, and so you can use it with plain Docker (or Compose) without trying to manage hostname-to-IP mappings.
You talk about needing to share a cookie domain.  In this example everything is served from the same host name and port, so the services can share cookies.  None of the service-to-service calls will be cross-origin calls (if service 1's in-browser application fetches /2/info.json it is on the same domain) and so CORS rules won't matter in this setup either.
